What is the pipe operator "|>" in BigQuery SQL?
The following SQL is not valid:
WITH foo AS (SELECT 1)
FROM bar a
WHERE x = y

However, it produces an interesting error message in the BigQuery UI:
Syntax error: WHERE not supported after FROM query; Consider using pipe operator `|> WHERE` at [3:1]

I like pipe operators in general, so I Googled but found nothing.
ChatGPT told me something, so I tested it
SELECT * FROM bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare
|> WHERE word_count > 100

but I can not make it work.
Pipe query syntax not supported at [2:1]

(Maybe it simply hallucinated.)
So what is the pipe operator "|>" in BigQuery SQL and how can it be used?

@kiranmathew Thanks! It's funny then that the error message from the BigQuery UI suggests using this (not implemented) operator. :D

Hi @Tobias Hermann,I am agreeing with you and it seems to have to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

Thanks, I've opened an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/340202288

To date, an enrollment form must be completed to use the pipe operator:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pipe-syntax-guide

